# Nodejs spawn script.exe ENOENT

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron, ipc, electron-forge

I am getting Error on running exe in electron app. Path is correct but still it through error.

```
    Uncaught Error: spawn exe/0c8c86d42f4a8d77842972cdde6eb634.exe ENOENT
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267)
        at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84)
```

here is my Code:

```
const executable = execFile(
  'script.exe',
  parameter,
  {
    cwd: 'D:/My Data/VS Code/ReactJS/FrontEND/CrownAIO/src/app/components/task/Scripts',
  },
  (error: any, stdout: any, stderr: any) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('stderr', stderr);
      throw error;
    }
    console.log('stdout', stdout);
  }
);
```

Why does `execFile` throw the error?
How to appropriately run executables with args in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1):

Add an executable to your file `script.exe`, then hopefully your `parameter` var is an array. See the nodejs doc https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback

For example if i run a bash script with the execFile method, i would do:

```
execFile('bash', ['test.sh'], { cwd: '.' }, 
    (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(stdout)
    }
)
```

Another ex, run a nodejs program

```
execFile('node', ['test.js'], { cwd: '.' }, 
        (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout)
        }
    )
```

Note that here the cwd option is useless has it is set like it by default.

Comment: its not working..Error: spawn script.exe ENOENT

Comment: can you execute your file from the teminal ? can you update your post with the command include the executable please.

Comment: Also make sure your path is properly built bc ENOENT means no file has been found. You can do that cont pt = require('path').normalize('D:/My Data........') and pass the pt has cwd

Comment: Its path issued. I resolve it.. But how can I pass argument with spaces.. @Jerome

Comment: Each element separate with a space (exept the executable of course) should be one element of the array, for instance:  vim -u NONE file.ext  should be execFile('vim', ['-u', 'NONE', 'test.txt'], .......